# How to rotate viewForHeaderInSection

Tags: iphone, uitableview, resize

UITableView has **custom header UIView**, which contains UILabel. Since table has also section index at right side, I want to center the label in remaining space.

[image]

Problem is how to "center" label in same way, when **device is rotated** to landscape! I've tried both Interface Builder and code-only and something is always wrong.

**Restrictions:**

1. Label is as narrow as possible
2. Label must not be resized
3. Label must be always centered inside table width minus section index

One easy way to fix this would be making section header view detached from tableView right side. Tried to do it, failed. Here's some code from **viewForHeaderInSection**:

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width - 32, 50.0f);
// MAGIC 32 for SectionIndexTitles

UIView *view = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];

UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Courier" size:20];
label.text = @"Section title long";
label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

CGSize labelSize = [label.text sizeWithFont:label.font
                          constrainedToSize:frame.size
                              lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeClip];
label.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, labelSize.width, labelSize.height);
label.center = CGPointMake(frame.size.width/2.0f, kHeaderHeight/2.0f);

label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
```

Any ideas welcome! Can't even recall how many different ways I have failed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey, set up as following in the IB:
Disable all autoresizing functionalities (no flexible width, height, nor any left, bottom, top, right).

Should do the job :)

To support the magic 32 pixels, try to position your Label as you need it.
That means:
Position it in the center of your UIView and move it 16 pixels to the left, now don't change the frame programmatically, else the "wonderful" auto-positiong will be manipulated what we don't really want to :)

Comment: Nope, relative position remained ok, but within whole UIView. I need center within UIView MINUS 32 magical pixels reserved for  section index...

Comment: Label width is dynamic, I have no idea what it is in advance. Thus have to resize label frame in code to minimize it...

Comment: On the one hand, you write "Label must not be resized" and on the other hand, the width is flexible :/ Did you set the flexibleWidth-"arrow" in the interface builder? else write in your code: `label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingMaskFlexibleWidth` not flexible left or right

Comment: Yep, it's a bit complicated :) Anyway, thanx to you it's now solved! I was missing one view: sectionHeader is full size due tableView, middleView for 32 pixels and label centered in that. Rotates now beautifully!